# Filling List in VBA with a loop

Tags: excel, vba

I've got a problem with populating a ValidateList. Here is my Code:

```
For i = 2 To letzteZeile

Do While ws.Cells(i, 3).Text = ws.Cells(i + 1 + j, 3).Text

        j = j + 1
Loop


If j > 0 Then

    dvList = ws.Cells(i, 1)

Do While k < j

              k = k + 1
              dvList = dvList + ", " + ws.Cells(i + k, 1)
Loop


With ws.Cells(i, "FT").Validation

    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=dvList
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True

End With

End If

Next i
```

So what do I want to do?

I want to go through several rows, look for duplicates and then put data belonging to the duplicates in one dropdown menu.

I collect the data in "dvList" (String) and put in into the list in FT.

But somehow the String I collect has an apostrophe at the beginnig, and my dropdown menu has only field with " 'Data1, Data2, Data3 ".

Any thoughts on how to solve my problem?

(I'm not 100% sure, if this kind of dropdown menu is the right one.)
((In the very very end - if possible - I want to put links to other worksheets into that dropdown menu.))

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete solution to any and all problems, only a **next step:**

***1.*** replace:

```
dvList = dvList + ", " + ws.Cells(i + k, 1)
```

with:

```
dvList = dvList & "," & ws.Cells(i + k, 1)
```

(we remove that extra blank associated with the comma)

***2.*** check dvList just before the **With** statement by including:

```
MsgBox dvList
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't change anything, besides the missing blanks (;

Comment: **What does the MsgBox say??**

Comment: I just reformatted the whole table and there are now no more apostrophes O.o

MsgBox says "Data,Data1,Data2"